# $M$ is semisimple iff every monomorphism $N \rightarrow M$ splits

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am having some trouble with the following problem:

> Prove that $M$ is a semisimple $R$-module if, and only if, for every monomorphism $j: N \rightarrow M$ and every morphism $f: N \rightarrow N'$, there exists some $f': M \rightarrow N'$ such that $f' j = f$.

I was able to prove the $(< =)$ part of the problem, but I'm stuck in the other way around. Could anyone point out some strategy to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is semisimple. Let $j : N \to M$ a monomorphism and $f : N \to N'$ just a morphism. Then, in virtue of the equivalences given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Definition), $j(N)$ is a direct summand of $M$, and so there exists a submodule $M'$ of $M$ such that $M = j(N) \oplus M'$. Define then $f' : M \to N'$ by $j(n)+m' \mapsto f(n)$ for $n \in N$ and $m' \in M'$.

Comment: Saying every submodule is a direct summand is more or less the same as saying every mono into it splits...!